# Uniform Continuity given the facts that |f(x)|>epsilon for x>N for some N>0 and that f is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I am given this question:

Let $D=[0,∞)$ and let $f:D→R$ be a continuous function.  Suppose that for all $ε\>0$, there is $N>0$ such that $|f(x)|<ε$ for all $x>N$.  Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$.

The definition of uniform continuity is given by:

For all $ε>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y$ $\epsilon$ $D$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<ε$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose by way of contradiction that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $D$. Thus, for suitable $\epsilon > 0$, we can find sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $D$ such that 
$$
|x_n-y_n | < \frac{1}{n}, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
and 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}\tag{$\ast$}
|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \geq \epsilon, \quad \text{for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.}
\end{equation}
Now, $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are either both unbounded or both bounded. If they are both bounded, then we can find a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converging to some $x \in D$. Because $|x_n-y_n| < 1/n$ for all $n$, this implies that $y_{n_k} \to x$ as well. By continuity, it follows that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} |f(x_{n_k})-f(y_{n_k})| = 0
$$
which contradicts \eqref{eq:1}. Hence, $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ must be both unbounded. In this case, we can pass to a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $x_{n_k} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$. As above, we must have $y_{n_k} \to \infty$ as well. On the other hand, the assumptions on $f$ ensure that 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0
$$
whence 
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} |f(x_{n_k}) - f(y_{n_k})| = 0
$$
as well. Again, this contradicts \eqref{eq:1}.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there is $N$ such that $\mid f(x) \mid < \epsilon$ for all $x > N$.
Since $[0,N]$ is compact $f$ is u.c on $[0,N]$, so there is $\delta > 0$ such that $\mid f(x) -f(y) \mid < \epsilon$ whenever $\mid x -y \mid < \delta, x, y \in [0,N]$. Yet this inequality is obvisouly true on $[N,\infty)$, so $f$ is u.c on $D$.

If $x \in [0,N]$ and $y \in [N, \infty), \mid x-y \mid <\delta$ then : $\mid f(x) -f(y) \mid \leq \mid f(x) -f(N) \mid + 2\epsilon \leq 3 \epsilon$.

Comment: It is common when students give the argument this way, that they forget to justify the case $x\in[0,N]$ and $y\in[N,\infty)$.

Comment: @user647486 Right, I added this case